# Unable to upgrade from 17.04 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, 17.04, update-manager, do-release-upgrade

I am still using ubuntu 17.04 (Because some features were not working in 17.10). Now I want to upgrade to 18.04. But update manager is showing that "Upgrade from zesty to bionic is not supported with this tool."
When tried to upgrade from terminal, it is also showing the same. What can I do now ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) and [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: The 17.04 to 17.10 upgrade path was tested, as was 17.10 to 18.04.  You're outside of the tested upgrade path so you've accepted the additional risk. Myself I'd backup your data, and do a install from install-media; using something else & 'not format' to save yourself the hassle of restoration of data, and see how it performs. If you have issues; you can always clean install 18.04 then restore your data from backups.  If you wish to go the upgrade path (17.04 -> 18.04) - it's your choice (I've done it for other jumps, but remember you've accepted the extra risk)

Comment: If stability matters to you - stick to LTS (long-term-support) releases as far less risks are taken with those and subsequently they are more stable.

Comment: @guiverc what is LTS ? Because stability matters to me. I don't want to do frequent upgrades.

Comment: LTS = long-term-support releases.  Ubuntu 17.04 means the 2017.April (yy.mm) release of Ubuntu which is EOL as now is the 17.10 (2017.October) release; so the only Ubuntu releases with support are 14.04 LTS (2014.April), 16.04 LTS (2016.April) & 18.04 LTS (2018.April).  The LTS or long-term-support releases are the more stable; if you were using for example 16.04 LTS - you haven't yet been offered the 18.04 LTS release upgrade; as for stability purposes that jump only gets offered when 18.04.1 LTS comes out (later this month) - ie. for maximum stability reasons.

Comment: Can't answer, but currently zesty is in old-releases and artful still in archive, upgrade to bionic works like this: Download http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/artful.tar.gz and verify using http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/artful/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/artful.tar.gz.gpg then extract the archive and execute `sudo ./artful --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText` Then do the normal upgrade to 18.04